# Are cookies considered part of the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, document-ready

I am writing some Javascript and I know I have to document-ready anything that will modify the DOM tree. I also need to perform some work on cookies. Are these considered part of the DOM tree (meaning I would have to document-ready them)? I don't believe so, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cookies aren't part of the DOM, they're part of the request/response headers of your HTTP request.

Cookies are really part of state management of your HTTP request (or web application).  The DOM is just the representation of your data.  You can have cookies with JSON or XML payloads, too.

Comment: Furthermore, cookies are not even related to HTML in general. You can send cookies to the server even if you request a picture.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I agree; they're just another mechanism involved with HTTP requests.  Your HTTP conversation could be solely with cookies.  Not sure I'd recommend that, though.  :)